# Cocos2d adding children in a loop : Child cannot be added

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am quite new to Objective-C and Cocos2d, and i don't really understand why i am getting the following error with the following code. Could you please help ?

```
- (NSArray *) menuItemsArray
{   
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc];
    for (Player * player in playersArray) {
        NSLog(@"creating menu item with image %@",player.imageFilename);
        CCLayer *newPage = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
        CCMenuItemImage *titem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:player.imageFilename
                                                    selectedImage:player.imageFilename
                                                           target:self selector:@selector(playerSelected:)];

        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: titem, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);

        NSLog(@"before adding item to layer");
        //[titem removeFromParentWithCleanup:YES];
        [newPage addChild:titem];
        //[newPage release];
        NSLog(@"after adding item to layer");
        [array addObject:newPage];

        /*
        [titem release];*/
        //[newPage release];
        //[menu release];
    }    
return array;
}
```

and i get the error:

```
2012-06-15 17:13:11.003 Killer[3222:707] *** Assertion failure in -[CCLayer     addChild:z:tag:], /Users/max/Documents/workspace/Killer/Killer/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:388
2012-06-15 17:13:11.006 Killer[3222:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'child already added. It can't be added again'
```

Sorry if this question is very low level... and thanks if you can help me ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to add created menuItem to two parents. add it to the menu only. Then add menu to the layer. Replace your line

```
[newPage addChild:titem];
```

with this one

```
[newPage addChild:menu];
```

and you will receive an array of pages for every player.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the question, now i realize i should have find that... Thanks again!

Comment: you can mark answer as valid to help others to find out the solution of such kind of problem =)